# Finding homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$ to $C_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

As my header suggests, I'm having a problem describing the homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$ to $C_{12}$ (the group of complex 12th roots of unity).

I understand that the group $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$ is comprised of the elements $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ and that $C_{12}$ is comprised of the elements $$\{1, e^{(\pi i/6)}, e^{(\pi i/3)}, i, e^{(2\pi i/3)}, e^{(5\pi i/6)}, -1, e^{(7\pi i/6)}, e^{(4\pi i/3)}, -i, e^{(5\pi  i/3)}, e^{(11\pi i/6)}\}.$$
 I also "know" that a homomorphism $\phi(G_1, *_1) \to \phi(G_2, *_2)$ must send $e_1$ ($\in G_1$) to $e_2$ ($\in G_2$).

I'm having trouble with the process itself. What steps do I take to see if the nth element of $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$ maps onto the $n$th element of $C_{12}$ (and would it be possible to provide an example)?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: its usually helps to check the elements's order in the origin and at the end. for example: you know that the order of $\{0\}$ equal to $1$ at $\Bbb Z_{12}$, and also $\{1\}$ order in $\Bbb C_{12}$ is 1 (as you said, $e_{\Bbb Z{12}}$ must go to $e_{\Bbb C{12}}$, so the map of them is $0 \mapsto 1$.
also, because both groups are cyclic, all you need to do is to check which element is the generator of every one of them, and define the homomorphism between the generators. in $\Bbb Z_{12}$ its quite easy to find one, its $1$, because $<1>=\Bbb Z_{12}$. can you find the generator of $\Bbb C_{12}$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a homomorphism $\alpha\colon\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to G$, where $G$ is any group, you can compose it with the canonical map $\pi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and get a homomorphism $\beta=\alpha\colon\pi$ such that $\beta(1)$ has order dividing $n$, because $n\in\ker\beta$, so $(\beta(1))^n=1$.

Conversely, if you are given an element $g\in G$ and the order of $g$ divides $n$, then we can define $\beta\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ by $\beta(z)=g^z$ and, since $g^n=1$, we know that $\ker\beta\supseteq n\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, by the homomorphism theorem, there exists $\alpha\colon \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to G$ such that $\beta=\alpha\circ\pi$.

You can also note that a homomorphism $\alpha\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to G$ is completely determined by the image of $1+\mathbb{Z}$, because $\alpha(k+n\mathbb{Z})=(\alpha(1+n\mathbb{Z}))^k$.

In your case the extra condition about the order being a divisor of $12$ is satisfied, so a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to C_{12}$ is basically the choice of an element which is the image of $1+n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $12$, depending on where you send a generator.   The homomorphism must send the generator to an element whose order divides $12$, but that's guaranteed, because $C_{12}$ has order $12$.  So you can send the generator wherever you want.

Here's a surjective one:  $h(1)=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{12}}$.  There are $4$ such.